# Prevent eclipse from renaming multiple files

Tags: eclipse, refactoring, automated-refactoring

I am using eclipse for a project that has multiple XML files in separate folders.

For example:

```
Folder A
    1.xml
    2.xml
    3.xml
Folder A_Large
    1_large.xml
    2_large.xml
    3.xml
```

If I rename `A_Large/3.xml` to `3_large.xml` it will rename *both* instances of `3.xml` leaving me with:

```
Folder A
    1.xml
    2.xml
    3_large.xml
Folder A_Large
    1_large.xml
    2_large.xml
    3_large.xml
```

I know I can hit `Preview` on the renaming dialog and specify what files will be renamed, but it never used to rename files like this, I must have changed some option.

How do I prevent eclipse from doing this?

Comment: How are you renaming it? Refactor >> Rename ? or F2 button? tried both and only that current file gets renamed... whats your eclipse version?

Comment: @ElyeM. Both F2 & Refactor->Rename do the same thing.

Comment: What is you eclipse version?

Comment: @ElyeM. Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2

Answer (score 1):

Select your file you wanna rename, go to  Refactor >> Rename , it should rename only that file.

Comment: When I do Refactor >> Rename it renames ALL occurrences.  This is why I think there is some option I accidentally turned on, but I have searched the entirety of Eclipse and can't find it.